# A confused senior citizen

Tags: carriers, samsung-galaxy-j5

I have an Android Samsung Galaxy J5 phone with SIM card slot No 1 with a Reliance Jio sim and SIM card slot no 2 with a BSNL 4G SIM.

On my BSNL line I do not have data but only for incoming/outgoing calls and other usual applications. I also have roaming and international calls.

On my JIO line I have usual Tariff facilities including data and national roaming.

What do I do to get the maximum out of my two SIM cards and what settings do I put for them??

Please advise as I am really confused.

Comment: What do you mean by getting maximum out of SIM cards? Moreover, JIO tariff and prime features are confined to India, so it is better if you delete those parts.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I do to get the maximum out of my two SIM cards and what settings do I put for them?

JIO only has a 4G VoLTE network and wouldn't work in 2G/3G. Does your phone support LTE + LTE may not be supported in your Galaxy J5. See if you can manually set your network and search for the BSNL sim from "Dual SIM settings".

> On my BSNL line I do not have data but only for incoming/outgoing calls and other usual applications.

You will have to switch primary SIM from JIO to BSNL for this as your phone doesn't support LTE+LTE. The JIO sim will probably lose signal when you switch BSNL to be the main SIM.

Also, you cannot use Mobile Data for both SIMs at the same time

Answer (score -2):

Your sim cards should work out of the box. You only need now than one if you travel from one county to another or one service area to another to avoid roaming charges. Your sim card allows you to connect to your network operator for regular phone calls. But to get higher speeds for browsing the internet look into WiFi, you will need to connect to a router.

Comment: How does that address the question of assigning wanted functionality to specific SIM cards? And obviously noone carries a WiFi router along while on the street (but uses it at home or in the office, when available). This question was specific to SIM cards and *mobile* traffic.